# when i am adding folder from other app to my app am getting error like no such file or directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am adding folder from other app folder and then put that folder in my app  and i import  folder files to my app file but i am getting error like no such file or directory while running.

Answer (score 3):

If you're attempting to move folders between running iPhone applications, you can't because of the application sandbox that isolates the applications from each other.

If you're attempting to add files and folders to an Xcode project, you need to make sure they are added to the appropriate target. If they are resources like images, sounds, plist etc you must have Xcode copy them to the project folder to ensure they are included in the final product.